# java CMYK to RGB values converter

Tags: java, html, xhtml, rgb, cmyk

Is there any easy way to achive this?

I need this because i get the CMYK values from a file and i need to use those values in a xhtml file by creating tags like this:

```
<item style="background-color:rgb(211,199,142);"> some text </item>
```

Comment: i didn;t, i don;t have the right formulae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the CMYK to RGB formulae:

```
double red = 255*(1-cyan)*(1-black);
double green = 255*(1-magenta)*(1-black);
double blue = 255*(1-yellow)*(1-black);
```

Where CMYK values range from 0 to 1 and RGB values range from 0 to 255.

Comment: i get a much brighter color

Comment: That's because CMYK is meant for print, while RGB is meant for the web; CMYK colors are always less vivid onscreen than their RGB counterparts.  However, if you print out the CMYK colors, they should look the same as the RGB do in a browser.